# Getting 'Not in GZIP format' error on untarring a tar.gz file after downloading from Artifactory

Tags: gradle, groovy, artifactory

I am able to upload and download a tar.gz file in my Gradle script using Artifactory REST API. But when I am trying to untar the file then I am receiving an error saying that the file is not in GZIP format. I think what I am missing here is a way to specify the file type while uploading it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On Artifactory, when I try to fix the checksum I get: 

`
Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type 
id (for class org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.artifacts.browse.treebrowser.tabs.general.GeneralArtifactInfo) 
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@338b472a; line: 1, column: 119]
`

Comment: What's the command you use to tar the file?

Comment: I downloaded the tar file and verified that it is valid. Then I uploaded that in Artifactory and when I am trying to download and untag it in my Gradle script I am getting this error. I am suspecting that I am missing something in the way I am uploading the tar file to Artifactory. The Rest API I am using to upload the file is: ${artifactory_url}/${repository}/${group}/${name}/${version}/${fileName}.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a `tar.gz` file you first un-gzip it then un-tar it...  Not the other way round.

Comment: Agree. My problem is that the downloaded file is not a valid tar.gz file.